# Is it expected for the Nikon D5100 and Sigma 150-500mm mounting to be very tight?

Tags: nikon-d5100, lens-mount, sigma

I have a query regarding the Sigma 150-500 mounting on a Nikon D5100.

I have got my Sigma 150-500mm today.... I am feeling that the lens is very tight to mount on my D5100. Is this expected?? I have other Nikon lenses like the 35mm f/1.8 which is mounting very smoothly, but the sigma 150-500 is *so* very tight that I need to put lot of force to mount it.

I initially thought the vendor may have sent me a different mount but cross-verified myself and with vendor and confirmed it is for Nikon. I am bit scared that it may hurt my cam mount or the lens mount itself if I mount multiple times. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

No it should not be tight to the point you feel like you are forcing it.  I had a 150-500 on my D90 and it mounted easily, same as all my other lenses.  You might want to check for a loose screw or bent flange at the base of the lens.  Do you see any scratch marks on the body where something may be rubbing/scraping against the mount?